# How to get a node by its partial name (contains)?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML document:

```
<ns0 ns0:action="publish" xmlns:mtc="urn:schemas-tenaris-com:industrial:mtc:mtccertificates" xmlns:ns0="urn:schemas-tenaris-com:industrial:mtd:mtdrequest">
    <ns0:values ns0:class="&#xD;&#xA;            " ns0:index="0">
        <ns0:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0"/>
        <ns0:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0">CONROE</ns0:value>
        <ns0:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0">tamsa_exp_manual</ns0:value>
        <ns0:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0">NA</ns0:value>
        <ns0:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0"/>
        <ns0:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0"/>
        <ns0:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0"/>
        <ns0:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0"/>
        <ns0:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0">true</ns0:value>
        <ns0:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0"/>
        <ns0:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0">123</ns0:value>
    </ns0:values>
</ns0>
```

What I want to do is to replace the node and all its children's names that contains the string "ns0".

What I tried is this:

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(pathXmlFile);
var ns0Nodes = xmlDocument.Descendants("ns0").ToList();
ns0Nodes.ForEach(node => node.Name = "NewName");
xmlDocument.Save("MyNewFile.xml");
```

However, that only gets the nodes with the exact name, and I want to get the ones that contains the "ns0" string in the name. Tried using a xpath string but it throws an exception saying that specific characters (like "/") are not allowed for node names.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Expected output:

```
<mtc:request ns0:action="publish" xmlns:mtc="urn:schemas-tenaris-com:industrial:mtc:mtccertificates" xmlns:ns0="urn:schemas-tenaris-com:industrial:mtd:mtdrequest">
    <mtc:values ns0:class="&#xD;&#xA;            " ns0:index="0">
        <mtc:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0"/>
        <mtc:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0">CONROE</ns0:value>
        <mtc:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0">tamsa_exp_manual</ns0:value>
        <mtc:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0">NA</ns0:value>
        <mtc:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0"/>
        <mtc:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0"/>
        <mtc:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0"/>
        <mtc:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0"/>
        <mtc:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0">true</ns0:value>
        <mtc:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0"/>
        <mtc:value ns0:class="" ns0:index="0">123</ns0:value>
    </mtc:values>
</mtc:request>
```

I'll have to change the attributes also, but that's another issue I'll face later, since that's not what I asked in the first place.

Comment: Can you provide a valid XML sample (this should have `xmlns:ns0="..."` somewhere)? And give us an example of the expected output?

Comment: If it were as simple as written, you would use `xmlDocument.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.NamespaceName.Equals("ns0")).ToList();`, but you may *(read: probably will)* have to correctly define your namespace first...

Comment: @CharlesMager Ok. I've edited the post with the xmlns and the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "ns0" parts are the namespace prefix the corresponding names belong to, as defined in one of the ancestor nodes.  In your case:

```
xmlns:ns0="urn:schemas-tenaris-com:industrial:mtd:mtdrequest"
```

To search for elements with that namespace (an element that is prefixed by `ns0`), you need to search for names with that namespace.

```
var ns0Name = "urn:schemas-tenaris-com:industrial:mtd:mtdrequest";
var query = doc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.NamespaceName == ns0Name).ToList();
```

Then to change the names to the other namespace, you need to create new names for them:

```
XNamespace mtc = "urn:schemas-tenaris-com:industrial:mtc:mtccertificates";
foreach (var e in query)
    e.Name = mtc + e.Name.LocalName;
```

Comment: Nicely explained. Thanks a lot.

This fixed the issue AND the attribute name issue as a bonus.